# Intellij - what is this strange selection, and how do I turn it off?

Tags: intellij-idea

See the screenshot below to see what I mean. Basically, Intellij only highlights the box I draw with the cursor, but leaves the rest of the editor untouched. I have no idea why it happens, and the only way to resolve it for now is to close and reopen the editor. I have observed the same behavior on a Linux box and a MacBook, both when editing Java and PHP files, so I am not sure it's a bug.

[image: bad intellij selection is bad]

The desired behaviour is standard row selection, i.e. highlight all rows which I drag the cursor over.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

I think you have enabled 'column selection'.

Option can be toggled via these methods:

> [Menu Bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_bar) -> `Edit` -> `Column selection mode`

> Document Body -> `Right Click` -> `Column selection mode`

> Keyboard Shortcut -> `ALT + SHIFT + INSERT`

Comment: Facing this issue today and got it fixed. Thankx @pveentjer

Comment: i accidentally choose this option and forgot how to disable. my whole DX became nightmare for a while. thank you

Answer (score 29):

The column select mode is enabled, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> to enable or disable this mode.

Comment: Thanks, I've enabled this stupid mode a couple of times by accident. So annoying.

Comment: There seems to be a difference in my newest version as of 21.1.3 - to select a rectangle I now need ALT and SHIFT. Previously I only needed ALT.

Comment: @BadHorsie, that stupid mode probably has saved me hours of repetitive cut-pastes or RegEx find-replace sessions. The drag-column-select that you see is useful when text elements are functionally aligned in your file, but in column select mode it might be even more useful when you figure out you can hold Option (IIRC—on Mac) then click multiple times to get multiple cursors where you click. Then, you can use text navigation/select tools as normal incl. copy, cut, and paste. Next time you have 20 (or 200?) lines you need to do the same op on, column select lets you do it once instead of 20x

Comment: Muchas gracias! My day is made whole again

Answer (score 26):

Shift-command-8 to toggle it back and forth on OSX.

Answer (score 1):

- Right click when in open file and de-select this option:
- Can be removed from Right click pop-menu from File>Settings>Follow the screenshot.

[image]
[image]